# Setting up Raspberry Pi hotspot with bridge. Dnsmasq unable to start

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, dnsmasq

I'm currently following this tutorial on setting up a access point and bridge on a Raspberry Pi:

http://imti.co/post/145442415333/raspberry-pi-3-wifi-station-ap

I have been trying to run dnsmasq and am getting the following errors:

```
$ sudo dnsmasq
dnsmasq: unknown interface uap0


$ sudo service dnsmasq start
Job for dnsmasq.service failed. See 'systemctl status dnsmasq.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

$ sudo dnsmasq --test
dnsmasq: syntax check OK.

$ systemctl status dnsmasq.service 
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/dnsmasq.service.d
           └─50-dnsmasq-$named.conf, 50-insserv.conf-$named.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-06-19 14:23:18 UTC; 18s ago
  Process: 21708 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 21704 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I have gone over and made sure that everything in the tutorial is done correctly, but I really have no idea what's going on in "/etc/init.d/dnsmasq". So I wouldn't want to mess around with that right away. If you need to see any files of mine to see what's going on, I will provide, though they are all the same as the ones in the link.
I'm not much of a networker normally, so apologies in advance if I'm not understanding something obvious.

ANy help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!